# pyparsing quantitative is not comutative

Tags: python, pyparsing

Why `ZeroOrMore(a) | ZeroOrMore(b)` is not like `ZeroOrMore(a | b)`?

I trying a simple lisp dialect and I step to this problem so this works

```
from pyparsing import *

ID = Word(alphas)
NUM = Word(nums)
LP = Literal('(').suppress()
RP = Literal(')').suppress()
atom = ID | NUM
expr = Forward()
e = ZeroOrMore(atom|expr)
expr << Group(LP + e + RP)


r = expr.parseString('(foo bar 1 (tar))')
print(r)
```

While this gives parser error at second `(`.

```
from pyparsing import *

ID = Word(alphas)
NUM = Word(nums)
LP = Literal('(').suppress()
RP = Literal(')').suppress()
atom = ID | NUM
expr = Forward()
e = ZeroOrMore(atom) | ZeroOrMore(expr)
expr << Group(LP + e + RP)


r = expr.parseString('(foo bar 1 (tar))')
print(r)
```

Comment: The second doesn’t let you mix atoms and expressions.

Comment: The first form allows zero or more of `atom|expr`, so for instance it allows `atom expr`.  The second allows zero or more `atom`, *or* zero or more `expr`.  It does not allow `atom expr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second doesn’t let you mix atoms and expressions.

As you define it, the parentheses around `tar` make it an expression. Combined with the other parts of that list, you have atoms and an expression, and the second grammar doesn’t permit that mixing. It only allows a bunch of atoms OR a bunch of expressions, where expressions need parentheses.